# ESQL aggregation `COUNT()` in nested query

Tags: asp.net, count, aggregate-functions, entity-sql

I have an ASP.NET page get request with url parameter of SQL for AJAX to get JSON response.

E.g.: `url: 'GridService.aspx?query=SELECT VALUE s.Name, s.Email FROM ModelContainer.StudentSet AS s'` will get information of `Name` and `Email`.

In order to implement the paging with [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/), I have to add total count of this query to the JSON response.

But the following query will not work with ESQL:

```
SELECT VALUE COUNT(0) FROM (SELECT VALUE s.Name, s.Email FROM ModelContainer.StudentSet AS s)
```

This is because two columns are selected in the child query. And the following could work:

```
SELECT VALUE COUNT(0) FROM (SELECT VALUE s FROM ModelContainer.StudentSet AS s)
```

Since **I don't want to select unnecessary columns**, I'm wondering if someone could give an example of making the former one work. Note that neither `Name` nor `Email` is PK.

Comment: Do NOT under any circumstance execute a query that came in the request query string. Google sql injection

Comment: @user1429080 Yes, I understand. But how to implement so much query requests?